# Vuejs OnMounted add a class to element with native js

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have a bit of a mixed application, that is SLOWLY being converted to a vuejs application.
So in instances like this, I have to combine regular js and vuejs.

I have a table being loaded with Vue js (Vue 3 Easy Data table), and on that I have some tooltips that are being added.
But I need to add a class to the TD.
I have access to the data inside, but not the td.

So I am trying to make this work, but hasToolTip is always empty, like it looks before the table is rendered. The code works fine if I fire it off in the console, but not directly here.

```
onMounted(() => {
  const hasToolTip = document.getElementsByClassName("hasTooltip");
  console.log("hasToolTip 2",hasToolTip.length);
  for(let i = 0; i < hasToolTip.length; i++){
    const parent = hasToolTip[i].parentElement;
    if(hasToolTip[i] !== null && parent !== null){
      parent.classList.add("tooltip-container");
    }
  }
});
```

Any tips to what I am doing wrong?

- Easy data table : https://hc200ok.github.io/vue3-easy-data-table-doc/

Comment: Please include a complete minimal repro in your question, and preferably a link to a working repro in something like StackBlitz.

Comment: Please expand on "I have some tooltips that are being added."

Comment: https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick

Comment: Are you _sure_ that everything is rendered by the time the component is mounted? It could be that the tooltips and such are not actually present yet. You could try running your code with `requestAnimationFrame`, or even just a `setTimeout` for debugging (or, as Lawrence said, there's `nextTick`).

Comment: And please add a link to "Vue 3 Easy Data Table" so that I can simply look at it instead of trying to find it and hoping I found the right thing.

Comment: I am fairly new to Vue, so its difficult to produce a repro.

Comment: I added a link for the easy data table doc.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes I am adding a tooltip to the content of the td, but since there are styling for overflow etc, the tooltip is being cut off. So with a class on the specifc td's I'm trying to fix that.

Comment: I think your stuff isn't actually finished rendering on the screen in the onMounted. Try putting your code inside a setTimeout with a long duration inside of the onMounted. Does it work then?

Comment: @RoboKozo That works. I found onUpdated which seems to make it work now. But is that the correct use ?

Answer (score 0):

onUpdated seems to make it work, if that is entire the right way, I cannot say.
But it works for now.

```
onUpdated(() => {
  const hasToolTip = document.getElementsByClassName("hasTooltip");
  console.log("hasToolTip 2",hasToolTip.length);
  for(let i = 0; i < hasToolTip.length; i++){
    const parent = hasToolTip[i].parentElement;
    if(hasToolTip[i] !== null && parent !== null){
      parent.classList.add("tooltip-container");
    }
  }
});
```